# Error: " MSVCCompiler' object has no attribute 'compiler_so " Appears whenver I try to compile a GitHub library

Tags: python, c++, compiler-errors, gpu, nvidia

Good Afternoon,

I'm currently trying to create a program that utilizes Python language to run Microsoft's Azure Kinect camera (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kinect-dk/)

The camera utilizes C++ to run it's developer kits. However, I recently discovered a GitHub library online that converts the C++ toolkit into Python (https://github.com/jrterven/KinZ-Python)

However, every time I try to run the `pip install .` command to implement the GitHub library, I'm met with an error that states:

```
AttributeError: 'MSVCCompiler' object has no attribute 'compiler_so'
```

Along with an extremely long paragraph of errors (which I can post if necessary).

The GitHub library (KinZ) states that you need to have a computer with CUDA (in which you NEED an Nvidia GPU for). But the error still occurs.

Supposedly, the reason is due to the `compiler_so` not supported on Windows and it doesn't matter as much if you have CUDA with the right Nvidia GPU to run it. (Yes, I do have an NVidia GPU)

So I don't know what to do from here...